# ImageDataGenerator to get leveled dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have a fairly uneven dataset in the number of images per label (the largest is 700 and the smallest is 30).

So I thought that I could use ImageDataGenerator to generate more images for the labels with the least number of images and progressively with the rest of the labels until achieving a leveling of the number of images per label. Later he would carry out the training.

I've been thinking to get approximately the same number of images per label through several loops and transforms with ImageDataGenerator but I don't know if I'm doing it right because I think there may be an easier way or maybe I'm getting the wrong strategy to get a good training.

Comment: Why don't you make a list of files, apply the transformations/oversampling you need, and make a loader that will iterate through those files? Keras is high level, if you want more flexibility you need to go lower level.

Answer (score 0):

ImageDataGenerator does not create new images, it just batches your images and can apply some augmentations to them to create a slightly more diverse dataset.
What you can do is something like in this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/complete-image-augmentation-in-opencv-31a6b02694f5). You can iterate through the directories the images are stored in, and use openCV to augment them and then save them off again. It can easily multiply the number of any class you use it on.

Here's an example where it takes each image rotate any number of degrees you want it to and save off

```
from PIL import Image
import os

os.chdir('/path/to/image/directory')
names = os.listdir()
for i in names:
    os.chdir('/path/to/image/directory') #chdir to location of images
    img = Image.open(i).rotate(180) #90,180,270
    
    #Where you want to save to
    os.chdir('path/to/save/location')
    
    img.save(i)
    os.rename('%s' % i, '180_%s' % i)
```

You can copy the code above or use this [repo](https://github.com/rgbarishian/Image-Tools/blob/master/Rotate_Images.py)

Answer (score 0):

creating augmented images is one way of handling the imbalance. However there is another way which is to use the parameter class_weight in model.fit. This parameter is a dictionary that specifies the weight each individual class should have on the loss function when you train the model. For example say you have 1000 images of cats and 100 images of dogs. You would want the samples of dogs to have 10 times the weight of a sample of cats with respect to the loss. Since you are using the ImageDataGenerator you can get the needed class_weight dictionary with the code below

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
               'balanced',
                np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
                train_generator.classes)
```